# Can't get user browser with flask request

Tags: python, flask, request, user-agent

I'm trying to get browser name when requested and i'm getting **'Your browser is None!'**.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user_agent = request.user_agent.browser
    return 'Your browser is {}!'.format(user_agent)
```

But if I make a request:

```
    user_agent = request.user_agent
```

I get **'Your browser is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) *Chrome/104.0.0.0* Safari/537.36!'**
The browser name and version are in a string, but why can't i get it using:
`request.user_agent.browser`

Comment: Whats your expected output ?

Comment: 'Your browser is Chrome' or any other current browser.

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-python

Answer (score 1):

I think you just answered your own question. If `request.user_agent` returns a string and not an object then `request.user_agent.browser` doesn't exist. Therefore it will return none.

If you are trying to get the user agent because you want to know weather or not there using a mobile browser then perhaps you should use some regular expressions to check the string for key words, for example "Mobile". Here is a sample of some code I'm working on that does this exactly:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    browser = request.user_agent
    browser = re.search("Mobile", str(browser))

    if browser != None:
        return render_template("mobile-index.html") 
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

If you have another use for the user agent then perhaps you should find a solution to that specific problem. But that solution will probably require regular expressions to parse through that string anyway.